# проблема вставки utf8 в mysql из python

Tags: python

Всем добрый день! Ситуация такова: написал скрипт для работы с mySQL базой,данные в которой хранятся как utf8, скрипт работает, но при вставке utf8 данных, которые берутся с другой таблицы, спотыкается об ошибку 1064 mySQL, мол не понимаю символов '\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0'. Вот сам скрипт:

```
import MySQLdb
class mSQLDatabase:
    __host = 'localhost'
    __user = 'root'
    __passwd = ''
    __selectedDB = 'Database1'
    __receivedDB = 'Database2'
    __selectedconn = None
    __receivedconn = None
    def __init__(self):
    self.__selectedconn = MySQLdb.connect(self.__host,self.__user,self.__passwd,self.__selectedDB,use_unicode=True,
charset='utf8')
    self.__receivedconn = MySQLdb.connect(self.__host,self.__user,self.__passwd,self.__receivedDB,use_unicode=True,
charset='utf8')
def insert(self, query):
    print(query)
    cursor = self.__receivedconn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    self.__receivedconn.commit()

def query(self, query):
    cursor = self.__selectedconn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute(query)
    return cursor.fetchall()

#!/usr/bin/env python
import DatabaseClass
import codecs
db = DatabaseClass.mSQLDatabase()
db = DatabaseClass.mSQLDatabase()
query = db.query("select din from S_Din")
myset = set()
for row in query:
    myset.add(row.values()[0])
for name in myset:
    print(name)
    db.insert("INSERT INTO `Database2`.`discipline` (`name`) VALUES (%s)" %(name))
```

Comment: Какая версия python?

Comment: @Arnial версия 3.4

Comment: Насколько я знаю расширение MySQLdb не поддерживает python3 и врятли когда-нибудь будет. Проект умер.

Comment: @Arnial его можно юзать, если установить через pip. Но, если вы говорите, что проект умер, подскажите, что лучше юзать для связи с mysql.

Comment: Я использую [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) (обещает поддержку python >= 3.3). Вроде как есть ещё [CyMySQL](https://github.com/nakagami/CyMySQL/) (аналог PyMySQL частично переписанный на Cython для ускорения) но его не пробовал.

Comment: @Arnial спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вобщем решение таково: 
вместо  этого

```
db.insert("INSERT INTO `UniversityBeta`.`groups` (`groupn`) VALUES (%s)", %(name))

def insert(self, query):
    print(query)
    cursor = self.__receivedconn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    self.__receivedconn.commit()
```

юзать это:

```
db.insert("INSERT INTO `UniversityBeta`.`groups` (`groupn`) VALUES (%s)",name)
def insert(self, query, param):
    print(query)
    cursor = self.__receivedconn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query,param)
    self.__receivedconn.commit()
```

Это позволяет явно указать тип данных при выполнении запроса, что решает проблему конвертации данных между python и mysql.